# How to get the thicker/fatter bold font on latex

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I know I can make letters or symbols bold by using \mathbf such as \mathbf w, which gives the w below, but how can I get the kind of boldness for letters as below for x and t?

[image]

Comment: if you have the pdf for that math, you can check exactly which font it is using, but `\bm{\mathsf{x}}`   may do what you want (`bm` package)

Comment: another approach is to check out unicode-math, with luatex or xelatex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually *don't* want to reproduce that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{times}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\bsf}[1]{\textnormal{\sffamily\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}

%% the following two lines just to faithfully reproduce the picture
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{equation}{59}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{previous}
%%

We now use the training data $\{\bsf{t}|\bsf{x}\}$ to determine the values
of the unknown parameters $\mathbf{w}$ and $\beta$ by maximum likelihood. 
If the data are assumed to be drawn independently from the 
distribution~\eqref{previous}, then the likelihood function is given by
\[ \label{another}
p(\bsf{t}|\bsf{x},\mathbf{w},\beta)=
\prod_{n=1}^{N}\mathcal{N}(t_{n}|y(x_{n},\mathbf{w}),\beta^{-1}).
\]

\end{document}
```

Why not?

1. The sans serif letters are way too higher than the serif ones.
2. Math is in Computer Modern and text in Times.

If I switch to `mathptmx` rather than `times`, the output would be

[image]

A bit better, but not really state-of-the-art.

Other choices would be to replace `\usepackage{times}` with

#### `mtpro2` (in the `lite`) version

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
```

[image]

#### `newtx`

```
\usepackage{newtx}
```

[image]

#### `stix2`

```
\usepackage{stix2}
```

[image]